# How to specify a specific NIC to be used in an application written in c++ (boost asio)

Tags: c++, windows, boost, routes, boost-asio

I have a machine connected to multiple independent networks, each on a different NIC (Network Interface Card). The machine runs Windows 7.

I run an application on the machine which needs to connect to a specific IP through a specific NIC, using TCP. The application uses c++11 and boost asio (1.53.0) for networking, and the source can be changed.

What are the different reasonable ways to solve this problem (specify endpoint IP and NIC) in a Windows environment?

The current solution assigns the respective (blocks of) IPs to the right NIC in the the routing table - by using the command line "route" command - as persistent routes. That way the OS handles the problem, which is allowed but not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [`open()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/open/overload1.html) and [`bind()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/bind/overload1.html) the socket to an `endpoint` before connecting. In this example I'm binding it to the loopback interface, in your scenario you can bind to the interface for your NIC.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int
main()
{
    using namespace boost::asio;
    io_service ios;
    ip::tcp::socket sock( ios );
    sock.open( ip::tcp::v4() );
    sock.bind( ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 0) );
    sock.connect( ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 1234) );
}
```

I'm not a Windows programmer so I can't provide a more detailed example than this. I believe you can enumerate through the NIC interfaces using [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915.aspx). On Linux I would use [`getifaddrs(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).

Comment: So the bind endpoint specifies the NIC, while the connect endpoint is the usual target endpoint, correct? If that's correct so far, I'm stuck on how to get an endpoint that specifies a NIC.

Comment: @Peter yes you are correct, each endpoint specifies part of the TCP socket's 4-tuple: client IP, client port, server IP, server port. For the client endpoint, you should use the IP address for that NIC and an zero to chose an ephemeral port.

Comment: Thanks. So based on the additional information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594523/how-could-i-get-or-change-the-ip-address-of-a-disconnected-nic-in-windows
One could use a static property of the NIC, such as the MAC, to specify a NIC in a configuration. Then at runtime use an OS specific call - such as the ones you mentioned - to get the IP of the NIC with the specified MAC, and then use the NIC IP to bind the socket to a NIC.