# In Boost ASIO how can I set the source IP address to impersonate another server's IP address?

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio, impersonation, arp

I have a Boost ASIO-based C++ server program and I'd like to be able to set the source IP address used by TCP to that of another server. I know one can read the source and destination IP addresses but presumably they can be set as well?

Presumably if I set the "wrong" source IP address in the C++ code there will be some interaction with the network stack. Won't the network stack re-set the source IP address on the way out even if the C++ code is right? Is the right way to do this to write C++ ASIO code to pick a specific virtual network interface? One that is configured with the "wrong" static IP address? I have seen this before as a way to control the source IP address. Is that what I need to do instead?

I am wondering what the consequences of this would be. Having two machines with the same static IP address configured might cause the "normal" server to stop working completely, which would be bad.

I have both Windows and Linux ports of my server I can use in case the code proposed will work on one OS and not the other. I'm currently leaning towards Kali Linux as I can "arpspoof" the main server and effectively shut it off for a while.

Comment: This question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Figure out what you can or can't do on the networking part. Then if you need to code something up and have trouble with it, ask here.

Comment: I'll fix the question to make sure this is a programming question. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

One can set the source IP to an arbitrary address on outbound data by manually constructing both network and transport layer headers, then sending the headers and the desired payload to a [raw socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw).  The use of raw sockets may require elevated permissions, or may be disabled or restricted by the kernel, such as on some Microsoft [platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Furthermore, due to TCP's three-way handshake and unpredictable sequence numbers, the effectiveness of the forged TCP segment, outside of potential [TCP reset attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_reset_attack), is questionable.

Routing is a different topic and depends on the various routers and configurations.  For instance, devices may perform egress filtering and drop packets with a source address for which the device cannot validate.  Furthermore, the affects of an IP address conflict can vary, but it often results in an intermittent connection.

---

Boost.Asio provides a [`basic_raw_socket<Protocol>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_raw_socket.html) template that expects a type meeting the [Protocol](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Protocol.html) type requirement.  For instance, below is the start or a `raw` protocol:

```cpp
struct raw
{
  typedef boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<raw> endpoint;
  int type() const     { return SOCK_RAW;    }
  int protocol() const { return IPPROTO_RAW; }
  int family() const   { return PF_INET;     }
};

boost::asio::basic_raw_socket<raw> socket;
```

When dealing with raw sockets, the difficulty is often not in using Boost.Asio, but rather having to implement the Network and Transport wire protocol.  Below is a complete minimal example where I tried to keep it as simple as possible by creating a `raw` protocol and using `basic_raw_socket` to send a UDP message:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

/// @brief raw socket provides the protocol for raw socket.
class raw
{
public:
  ///@brief The type of a raw endpoint.
  typedef boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<raw> endpoint;

  ///@brief The raw socket type.
  typedef boost::asio::basic_raw_socket<raw> socket;

  ///@brief The raw resolver type.
  typedef boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver<raw> resolver;

  ///@brief Construct to represent the IPv4 RAW protocol.
  static raw v4()
  {
    return raw(IPPROTO_RAW, PF_INET);
  }

  ///@brief Construct to represent the IPv6 RAW protocol.
  static raw v6()
  {
    return raw(IPPROTO_RAW, PF_INET6);
  }

  ///@brief Default constructor.
  explicit raw()
    : protocol_(IPPROTO_RAW),
      family_(PF_INET)
  {}

  ///@brief Obtain an identifier for the type of the protocol.
  int type() const
  {
    return SOCK_RAW;
  }

  ///@brief Obtain an identifier for the protocol.
  int protocol() const
  {
    return protocol_;
  }

  ///@brief Obtain an identifier for the protocol family.
  int family() const
  {
    return family_;
  }

  ///@brief Compare two protocols for equality.
  friend bool operator==(const raw& p1, const raw& p2)
  {
    return p1.protocol_ == p2.protocol_ && p1.family_ == p2.family_;
  }

  /// Compare two protocols for inequality.
  friend bool operator!=(const raw& p1, const raw& p2)
  {
    return !(p1 == p2);
  }

private:
  explicit raw(int protocol_id, int protocol_family)
    : protocol_(protocol_id),
      family_(protocol_family)
  {}

  int protocol_;
  int family_;
};

///@ brief Mockup ipv4_header for with no options.
//
//  IPv4 wire format:
//
//  0                   1                   2                   3
//  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+   ---
// |version|header |    type of    |    total length in bytes     |    ^
// |  (4)  | length|    service    |                              |    |
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+    |
// |        identification         |flags|    fragment offset     |    |
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+  20 bytes
// | time to live  |   protocol    |       header checksum        |    |
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+    |
// |                      source IPv4 address                     |    |
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+    |
// |                   destination IPv4 address                   |    v
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+   ---
// /                       options (if any)                       /
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
class ipv4_header
{
public:
  ipv4_header() { std::fill(buffer_.begin(), buffer_.end(), 0); }

  void version(boost::uint8_t value) {
    buffer_[0] = (value << 4) | (buffer_[0] & 0x0F);
  }

  void header_length(boost::uint8_t value)
  {
    buffer_[0] = (value & 0x0F) | (buffer_[0] & 0xF0);
  }

  void type_of_service(boost::uint8_t value) { buffer_[1] = value; }
  void total_length(boost::uint16_t value) { encode16(2, value); }
  void identification(boost::uint16_t value) { encode16(4, value); }

  void dont_fragment(bool value)
  {
    buffer_[6] ^= (-value ^ buffer_[6]) & 0x40;
  }

  void more_fragments(bool value)
  {
    buffer_[6] ^= (-value ^ buffer_[6]) & 0x20;
  }

  void fragment_offset(boost::uint16_t value)
  {
     // Preserve flags.
     auto flags = static_cast<uint16_t>(buffer_[6] & 0xE0) << 8;
     encode16(6, (value & 0x1FFF) | flags);
  }

  void time_to_live(boost::uint8_t value) { buffer_[8] = value; }
  void protocol(boost::uint8_t value) { buffer_[9] = value; }
  void checksum(boost::uint16_t value) { encode16(10, value); }

  void source_address(boost::asio::ip::address_v4 value)
  {
    auto bytes = value.to_bytes();
    std::copy(bytes.begin(), bytes.end(), &buffer_[12]);
  }

  void destination_address(boost::asio::ip::address_v4 value)
  {
    auto bytes = value.to_bytes();
    std::copy(bytes.begin(), bytes.end(), &buffer_[16]);
  }

public:

  std::size_t size() const { return buffer_.size(); }

  const boost::array<uint8_t, 20>& data() const { return buffer_; }

private:

  void encode16(boost::uint8_t index, boost::uint16_t value)
  {
    buffer_[index] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buffer_[index + 1] = value & 0xFF;
  }

  boost::array<uint8_t, 20> buffer_;
};

void calculate_checksum(ipv4_header& header)
{
  // Zero out the checksum.
  header.checksum(0);

  // Checksum is the 16-bit one's complement of the one's complement sum of
  // all 16-bit words in the header.

  // Sum all 16-bit words.
  auto data = header.data();
  auto sum = std::accumulate<boost::uint16_t*, boost::uint32_t>(
    reinterpret_cast<boost::uint16_t*>(&data[0]),
    reinterpret_cast<boost::uint16_t*>(&data[0] + data.size()),
    0);

  // Fold 32-bit into 16-bits.
  while (sum >> 16)
  {
    sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
  }

  header.checksum(~sum);
}

///@brief Mockup IPv4 UDP header.
//
// UDP wire format:
//
//  0                   1                   2                   3
//  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+   ---
// |          source port          |      destination port        |    ^
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+  8 bytes
// |            length             |          checksum            |    v
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+   ---
// /                        data (if any)                         /
// +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
class udp_header
{
public:
  udp_header() { std::fill(buffer_.begin(), buffer_.end(), 0); }

  void source_port(boost::uint16_t value)      { encode16(0, value); }
  void destination_port(boost::uint16_t value) { encode16(2, value); }
  void length(boost::uint16_t value)           { encode16(4, value); }
  void checksum(boost::uint16_t value)         { encode16(6, value); }

public:

  std::size_t size() const { return buffer_.size(); }

  const boost::array<uint8_t, 8>& data() const { return buffer_; }

private:

  void encode16(boost::uint8_t index, boost::uint16_t value)
  {
    buffer_[index] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    buffer_[index + 1] = value & 0xFF;
  }

  boost::array<uint8_t, 8> buffer_;
};


int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Create all I/O objects.
  boost::asio::ip::udp::socket receiver(io_service,
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), 0));
  boost::asio::basic_raw_socket<raw> sender(io_service,
    raw::endpoint(raw::v4(), 0));

  const auto receiver_endpoint = receiver.local_endpoint();

  // Craft a UDP message with a payload 'hello' coming from
  // 8.8.8.8:54321
  const boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint spoofed_endpoint(
    boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("8.8.8.8"),
    54321);
  const std::string payload = "hello";

  // Create the UDP header.
  udp_header udp;
  udp.source_port(spoofed_endpoint.port());
  udp.destination_port(receiver_endpoint.port());
  udp.length(udp.size() + payload.size()); // Header + Payload
  udp.checksum(0); // Optioanl for IPv4

  // Create the IPv4 header.
  ipv4_header ip;
  ip.version(4);                   // IPv4
  ip.header_length(ip.size() / 4); // 32-bit words
  ip.type_of_service(0);           // Differentiated service code point
  auto total_length = ip.size() + udp.size() + payload.size();
  ip.total_length(total_length); // Entire message.
  ip.identification(0);
  ip.dont_fragment(true);
  ip.more_fragments(false);
  ip.fragment_offset(0);
  ip.time_to_live(4);
  ip.source_address(spoofed_endpoint.address().to_v4());
  ip.destination_address(receiver_endpoint.address().to_v4());
  ip.protocol(IPPROTO_UDP);
  calculate_checksum(ip);

  // Gather up all the buffers and send through the raw socket.
  boost::array<boost::asio::const_buffer, 3> buffers = {{
    boost::asio::buffer(ip.data()),
    boost::asio::buffer(udp.data()),
    boost::asio::buffer(payload)
  }};
  auto bytes_transferred = sender.send_to(buffers,
    raw::endpoint(receiver_endpoint.address(), receiver_endpoint.port()));
  assert(bytes_transferred == total_length);

  // Read on the reciever.
  std::vector<char> buffer(payload.size(), '\0');
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
  bytes_transferred = receiver.receive_from(
      boost::asio::buffer(buffer), sender_endpoint);

  // Verify.
  assert(bytes_transferred == payload.size());
  assert(std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end()) == payload);
  assert(spoofed_endpoint == sender_endpoint);

  // Print endpoints.
  std::cout <<
    "Actual sender endpoint: " << sender.local_endpoint() << "\n"
    "Receiver endpoint: " << receiver.local_endpoint() << "\n"
    "Receiver's remote endpoint: " << sender_endpoint << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
$ sudo ./a.out
Actual sender endpoint: 0.0.0.0:255
Receiver endpoint: 0.0.0.0:44806
Receiver's remote endpoint: 8.8.8.8:54321
```

As indicated in the output, although the true sender endpoint is `0.0.0.0:255`, the receiver believes the sender's endpoint is `8.8.8.8:54321`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bind`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bind.html) call to assign the source IP address and port.

If you do not call `bind` before `connect` the OS picks and binds the interface for you using the routing table.

The IP address must be the address of one of your host's interfaces. In other words, you cannot spoof your source IP using `bind` call.

Comment: Thanks, this is definite progress. The question then becomes "how does one add a bind() to a socket in Boost ASIO?"

Comment: @Tim37 I would look up the documentation.

Comment: OK, my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299476/how-to-specify-a-specific-nic-to-be-used-in-an-application-written-in-c-boost

Comment: The essence of my problem was to find where the bind() call was buried in Boost ASIO. I found this through another source.